# Decent FPS for my game but experiencing input lag

Tags: graphics-card, gaming

I play Ghost Recon Phantoms when my wife is not around and my baby is asleep.

My PC:
Ivy Bridge i3
8GB RAM
AMD 7730 (1GB GDDR5)
120GB Intel 330-series SSD

I play the game in medium graphics settings and it's perfectly fine. With FRAPS, it reports 60FPS.

When I bump up the graphics settings to high, FRAPS still show 60FPS, occasionally dropping to about 42FPS (depending on map). Visually it looks smooth, however, there is now a noticeable "input lag;" There is a slight delay in my mouse and keyboard movement. I don't experience this "input lag" when the graphics settings are set to medium.

Could it be my graphics card cannot keep up? But why are the frame rates still ok (40-60fps)?

Comment: What specific resolutions are "medium" and "high" graphics settings? Does it depend on the game, the GPU, the VRAM, or what?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common problem. It happens in many games and can be caused by quite a few factors. The higher the screen resolution the more noticeable it is (for me, at least).

However for Ghost Recons Phantoms it actually [seems to be part of the game design.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/243870/discussions/2/540738052815618343/)

> Negative mouse acceleration is part of the game design. It's to balance heavier weapons and prevent them from snap shooting.

There is also a [Youtube video made to reduce mouse lag for this particular game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpDdzva9Els). Settings are for NVIDIA but:

> I don't have AMD RADEON, but regarding one of my clan mate, who have
>   AMD. He achieve same result with Windowed mode and V-Sync."

### Reasons I can think of:

[**1. Prerender limit**](http://gtaforums.com/topic/427656-gta-iv-mouse-lag/)

During the rendering of scenes, the driver usually accepts commands for more than a single frame. This way the GPU doesn't stall the CPU until it's absolutely neccessary.

If the GPU accepts the command for too many frames ahead, additional mouse lag can be introduced, though. That means that there is a very slight delay between the moving of the mouse and the actual reaction on the screen.

You can get a faster reaction on your mouse movements in some games by lowering the limit. This might also cause a loss in framerate, though.

This settings should be in **Catalyst Control**. eg for NVIDIA it is **Manage 3D Settings>(MY_GAME)>Maximum Pre-rendered Frames.**

Also in Catalyst/NVIDIA CP, edit the option called "Power management mode" and set it to "Prefer maximum performance".

2. **Mouse Acceleration**

Sometimes this setting is enabled in *Mouse Properties* or a program like *Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Centre*. You can try to disable it and see if it makes any difference. More info on how to disable it the link below.

Make sure you have **Enhance pointer precision** unchecked in the Pointer Options tab of Mouse properties

3. **ATi Hotkey Poller**

The ATI Catalyst drivers include an ATI HotKey Poller service that has been [reported to cause input lag on certain system configurations](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5365-RXBN-5508). If you do not overclock your video card or otherwise use the ATI hotkeys, it is recommend that you disable this service if you are experiencing input lag in games.

1) Click Start -> Run

2) Type Services.msc and press Enter

3) Find the service "ATI HotKey Poller"

4) Right-Click on the service and select Properties

5) Change "Startup type" to Disabled

6) Click "Apply", then "Ok"

7) Reboot your computer

4. [Dedicated mouse/keyboard drivers](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/686485-Mouse-accel-lag-smoothing-whatever-you-want-to-call-it-Forums)

If dedicated drivers (like Setpoint for Logitech or the Razer drivers, etc) for hardware are installed, it is possible that the game mistakenly detects them as gamepads (lots of buttons not just left/right click).

You can uninstall the drivers, thus reverting your hardware to standard Microsoft ones.

5. [If you use Windows 8.1](http://www.howtogeek.com/175722/how-to-fix-mouse-lag-in-pc-games-on-windows-8.1/)

Windows 8.1 allows Windows to work better on high-DPI displays. As part of this, the way Windows deals with mice has changed. Games that don’t read raw mouse data may end up with laggy, freezing, or stuttering mouse movement.

This problem seems to primarily affect users with high-DPI or high-polling rate mice — in other words, gaming mice. Microsoft has only released a partial fix, but there’s a way to fix this problem in any affected game.

The patch is **KB2908279** - either get it from Windows Update or manually from Microsoft.

The patch above does two things. One, it creates a new type of compatibility flag in Windows. Two, it applies that compatibility flag to some of the most popular games affected by this problem.

Though I don't think the game in question is considered "less popular", if the patch doesn't work you can try to apply the compatibility option to the game on your own (the patch is still needed). The method is described in the link for 5).

Source: [Here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2198431)

If the above steps don't work, try following the steps described in the link below.

[Valve's tips for solving mouse lag.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5365-RXBN-5508)

[A guide (more advanced)](http://www.overclock.net/t/173255/cs-s-mouse-optimization-guide).